# How to iterate over Map using ngFor and display them in order on html in Angular 2+?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, hashmap, ngfor

I am using Angular 7.x.

I have implemented the code where using *ngFor, it iterates over Map and display them on html

```
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let data of map | keyvalue">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <p mat-line> {{data.value.name}} </p>           
          </div>            
      </mat-list-item>
```

It successfully shows a list but problem is it does not show them in order.

For example, if I add A and B to Map, it shows as

A B

However if I add another one, C, then it shows as

A
C
B

I want it to be as A B C, which is the order I inserted to Map.

If I console.log, then it shows as in order of I inserted but not on html.

I HAVE TO use MAP but I do not know how.

Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: you can get the help from this stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6nlftw

Comment: you mean that the array "map" is ordered and shows up in order on console... but not inside the <p mat-line> ??

Comment: @HrishikeshKale Thank you for your advice but t does not answer my question which is "how to display map in the order I inserted to Map". I can't use key or value to sort them in some kind of order.

Comment: @AkberIqbal No, map is not an array. It is Map, which is hashmap or dictionary in other languages. If I console.log(map), it shows as A B C but not on html using ngFor.

Comment: @Staytrippy there is no such concept of hashmap while rendering on HTML they are treated as a simple object.  a simple solution will assign it to the array and use.

Comment: can you include your actual json model

Answer (score 11):

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive
>   values) may be used as either a key or a value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

One solution is to do the following:

Add this method in your **TS**:

```
asIsOrder(a, b) {
   return 1;
}
```

Change your `keyvalue` pipe to `keyvalue: asIsOrder` in your **HTML**:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let data of map | keyvalue: asIsOrder">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p mat-line> {{data.value.name}} </p>           
    </div>            
</mat-list-item>
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31420

Comment: Hi @Emeric! you are awsome!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set values like this,

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  map = new Map<String, String>();

  constructor(){
   this.map.set("sss","sss");
   this.map.set("aaa","sss");
   this.map.set("sass","sss");
   this.map.set("xxx","sss");
   this.map.set("ss","sss");
   this.map.forEach((key: string,value: string) => {
   console.log(key, value);
});
}
}
```

it will show the list like this.

aaa --> sss

sass --> sss

ss --> sss

sss --> sss

xxx --> sss

That means the order of the list is dependent on your key.

- If the keys are numbers they are sorted by ascending order.
- If the keys are strings they are sorted by alphabetical order.
- If the keys are mixed i.e., one key is a string and another key is number
  then both are converted to strings, first sorted by numbers in ascending order and then sorted by strings in alphabetical order.
- If the key is undefined or null they are displayed at last.

  Try with this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-keyvalue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts